# Working on a Java GUI/Canvas project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, canvas

Hi I am new to GUI and Canvas in Java. I am working on a project where I will need a GUI/Canvas (still confused on the difference) that has three frames I guess. Basically it is an elevator project where on either side of the canvas there is a rectangular elevator object, and in the middle are buttons (stacked on top of each other) that are used to represent floors (so if you click on the button, the elevator moves to the same row as the button). I am stuck on how you would design the canvas for this. I have had some ideas regarding gridLayout and broderLayouts, but it is all a jumbled mess right now.

thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class UI extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList(); 
MyCanvas mainCanvas;

public UI()
{
  super("Example Frame");
    setSize(800,600);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);

  mainCanvas = new MyCanvas();

  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,1));

  //while(true)
  //{
   //   myCanvas.repaint();
    //}
  for(int i=1; i<13; i++)
  {   String s = Integer.toString(i);
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(s));
  }
  add(mainPanel);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Must you use Canvas and the AWT GUI library? Can't you use Swing instead? If so, then the key to getting unconfused is the Swing Tutorials: [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: So far I have this as my code in my constructor (I also have an action performed in this UI class), but when I compile nothing is showing up. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: Sorry about that, just added my code

Comment: What is the "MyCanvas" class?

Comment: It is a canvas that controls the building of the elevator objects, haven't really built that yet, was given some snippet of code to work with so put it in there. Want to get the thing showing with the buttons first before I add the elevators in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a loaded question.

If it's purely about layouts, then I'd use a series of compound components with there own layouts to achieve the result you need...

If it's about approaches, then it gets more complicated...

Basically, you want to seperate the areas of responsibilities.

From the question, there are two distinct models, a elevator model and a building model.

The elevator model controls where the elevator for an individual shaft is where as the building model controls things like, the number of floors, the individual elevator models, the algorithm to determine how an elevator is called to a floor...

The following is REALLY basic example of an idea.  It's missing (amongst other things) the logic needed to call an elevator to a floor or stateful information about the elevators (moving, waiting, open...)

[image]

```
public class Elevator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Elevator();
    }

    public Elevator() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BuildingPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum ElevatorShaft {
        Left,
        Right
    }

    public interface ElevatorModel {
        public int getFloor();
        public void setFloor(int floor);

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    }

    public class DefaultElevatorModel implements ElevatorModel {

        private int floor;
        private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

        public DefaultElevatorModel(int floor) {
            this.floor = floor;
            propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public int getFloor() {
            return floor;
        }

        @Override
        public void setFloor(int value) {
            if (value != floor) {
                int old = floor;
                floor = value;
                propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("floor", old, floor);
            }
        }

    }

    public interface BuildingModel {

        public int getFloorCount();
        public int getFloor(ElevatorShaft shaft);
        public ElevatorModel getElevatorModel(ElevatorShaft shaft);
        public void call(int floor);

    }

    public class DefaultBuildingModel implements BuildingModel {

        private int floorCount;

        private Map<ElevatorShaft, ElevatorModel> shaftManager;

        public DefaultBuildingModel(int floorCount) {
            this.floorCount = floorCount;
            shaftManager = new HashMap<ElevatorShaft, ElevatorModel>(2);
            shaftManager.put(ElevatorShaft.Left, new DefaultElevatorModel((int)Math.round(Math.random() * (floorCount - 1))));
            shaftManager.put(ElevatorShaft.Right, new DefaultElevatorModel((int)Math.round(Math.random() * (floorCount - 1))));
        }

        @Override
        public ElevatorModel getElevatorModel(ElevatorShaft shaft) {
            return shaftManager.get(shaft);
        }

        @Override
        public int getFloorCount() {
            return floorCount;
        }

        @Override
        public int getFloor(ElevatorShaft shaft) {
            return shaftManager.get(shaft).getFloor();
        }

        @Override
        public void call(int floor) {
            // This will need to determine which elevator should be called
            // and call that elevators model "setFloor" method...
        }

    }

    public class BuildingPane extends JPanel {

        public BuildingPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            BuildingModel model = new DefaultBuildingModel(3);

            Shaft leftShaft = new Shaft(model, ElevatorShaft.Left);
            Shaft rightShaft = new Shaft(model, ElevatorShaft.Right);
            ButtonsPane buttonsPane = new ButtonsPane(model);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

            add(leftShaft, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(buttonsPane, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(rightShaft, gbc);

        }

    }

    public class ButtonsPane extends JPanel {

        private BuildingModel model;

        public ButtonsPane(BuildingModel model) {

            this.model = model;

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            int floorCount = model.getFloorCount();
            ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

            for (int floor = floorCount; floor > 0; floor--) {

                JButton button = new JButton("Floor " + floor);
                button.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(floor));
                button.addActionListener(handler);
                add(button, gbc);

                gbc.gridy++;

            }

        }

        public BuildingModel getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                try {
                    int floor = Integer.parseInt(cmd);
                    getModel().call(floor);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public class Shaft extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage elevator;
        private BuildingModel buildingModel;
        private ElevatorShaft shaft;

        public Shaft(BuildingModel model, ElevatorShaft shaft) {

            this.buildingModel = model;
            this.shaft = shaft;

            buildingModel.getElevatorModel(shaft).addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (evt.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("floor")) {
                        // Need to update our position, this could
                        // be done via animation or directly call something
                        // like repaint..
                    }
                }
            });

            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);

            try {
                elevator = ImageIO.read(new File("elevator.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Elevator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        public BuildingModel getBuildingModel() {
            return buildingModel;
        }

        public ElevatorShaft getShaft() {
            return shaft;
        }

        public int getFloorCount() {
            return getBuildingModel().getFloorCount();
        }

        public int getFloor() {
            return getBuildingModel().getFloor(getShaft());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            Dimension size = new Dimension(elevator.getWidth(), elevator.getHeight() * getFloorCount());
            Insets insets = getInsets();

            size.width += (insets.left + insets.right);
            size.height += (insets.top + insets.bottom);

            return size;

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int x = insets.left;
            int y = insets.top;
            int height = getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

            int floor = getFloor();
            y = height - (elevator.getHeight() * (floor + 1));
            g.drawImage(elevator, x, y, this);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: nice picture :-) Nitpicking, though: all panel extensions except the Shaft are not necessary (some like me might even call them evil ;-)

Comment: @Kleopatra Yes and no (as always), I like the fact that I can isolate the logic of the buttons controls and the action listener for the buttons. It could allow me to drop a replacement into that position (if I was using a getter for the panel instead of creating it inline) - but it's still a fair point

Answer (score -1):

How I would change your class is like so (note this is pseudo code you'll need to actually implement an action listener for handling button presses)-

```
public class UI extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList(); 

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 50;
int height = 50;

public UI()
{
  super("Example Frame");
  setSize(800,600);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);    

  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,1));

  for(int i=1; i<13; i++)
  {   String s = Integer.toString(i);
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(s));
  }

  add(mainPanel);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
}

onButtonPress(int buttonNumber){
    y = buttonNumber * 10;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Added a test actionperformed to make it compile, but how do I make it show/draw all the buttons?

Comment: try specifying the size and location of the buttonPanel. I'm not good with layouts I generally use a gui builder

Comment: @ghostbust555 "Layouts, you must learn layouts" ;)