# Java GUI class buttonPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, paint

I want a Panel of 12 buttons to show up in my GUI. But for some reason they are not showing up. I don't know what is wrong with my code right now. I haven't put anything in my action performed method yet, but I will (right now I am just focused on getting the buttons to show). So could someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

Edit* This is all that is in my GUI Class, I want two canvases of elevator objects to show (nothing is showing)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(1000, 1000);

MyCanvas leftCanvas = new MyCanvas();
MyCanvas rightCanvas = new MyCanvas();
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>(); 
JPanel buttonPanel, leftPanel, rightPanel;

public GUI()
{
  super("Elevators");
    //setSize(800,800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setVisible(true);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.add(leftCanvas);
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.add(rightCanvas);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();     
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,1));   
    buttonPanel.setSize(900,900);

    add(mainPanel); 

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        buttonList.add(new JButton(""+i));
        JButton btn = buttonList.get(i);
        buttonPanel.add(btn);
    }
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainPanel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    createAndShowGui();
}
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return PREF_SIZE;
}
private static void createAndShowGui() {
  UI frame = new UI();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
//public static void main(String[] args) {
  //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    // public void run() {
      //  createAndShowGui();
   //  }
  //});
//} 
//public void paint(Graphics g)
//{

// }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

}

}
```

Here is my Canvas class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyCanvas extends Canvas 
{
private Elevator e;

int xPos =0;
int yPos=0;

public MyCanvas()
{
   setSize(600,600);
   repaint();
}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   g.fillRect(xPos,yPos,100, 100);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    repaint();
}
public void setElevator(Elevator ev)
{
    e = ev;
}
}
```

[image: This is what I am trying to accomplish w/ the project]

Comment: No buttons are showing up at all? Is the buttonPanel showing up? Have you tried putting a border around it?

Comment: This won't answer your question, but you shouldn't use BorderLayout constraints when adding to a GridLayout-using container (mainPanel). i.e., `mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` makes no sense. For better help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http:sscce.org).

Comment: haven't tried putting a border around it, but even w/o a border then panel and the buttons should show right?

Comment: Not if the container is too small to be seen! That's why sometimes using a border is a good debugging technique. Delete it later.

Comment: You've got something calling the constructor? (or instantiating this) some other class or the main in this class?

Comment: Yep as I suggested, he needs to create and post an SSCCE so we can actually run and modify the code, see what is wrong and help him correct it.

Comment: Edited my code, I removed everything not needed, and that is all I have so far. It compiles, but the buttons don't show.

Comment: @Big_Fan: you need to add a main method, you should *never* have an empty `paint(...)` method, and you should rarely ever override that method to begin with.

Comment: Problem with displaying, edited using MadPragrammer's solution

Comment: The lower picture is what I am trying to accomplish w/ this project

Comment: I would never recomment overriding paint(..) of `JFrame`. Rather add a `JPanel` to `JFrame` and override `paintComponent(...)`...

Answer (score 4):

You overrode the frame's `paint` method...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

}
```

But failed to call `super.paint(g)`....

One of the responsibilities of `paint` is to paint the child components...

**UPDATED**

Also, the call to `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout())` is messing with your layout as the constraints have being discarded, meaning that the layout manager doesn't know what should go where

**UPDATED Example**

I was able to produce this...

[image]

With this

```
public class Elevator02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Elevator02();
    }

    public Elevator02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                UI ui = new UI();
                ui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            }
        });
    }

    public class UI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList();
        JPanel buttonPanel;

        public UI() {
            super("Elevators");
            setSize(200, 400);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12, 1));

            add(mainPanel);

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                buttonList.add(new Button("" + i));
                buttonPanel.add(buttonList.get(i));
                buttonList.get(i).addActionListener(this);
            }
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        }

//        public void paint(Graphics g) {
//        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason not getting that, I edited my post and added a picture to show the problem

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to tell you.  Have you tried resizing the window?

Comment: How would I change this if I want them to be just in the center of the screen? For example I want to have 3 panels (the button panel being the center one) w/ two canvases on the panels to the right and left of the button panel. I tried creating canvas objects and adding them to new panels, but that did not work. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You mean like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022853/working-on-a-java-gui-canvas-project/13024192#13024192)

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

Before (your provided code)

```
this.add(mainPanel); 

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        buttonList.add(new Button(""+i));
        buttonPanel.add(buttonList.get(i));
        buttonList.get(i).addActionListener(this);
    }
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

After: (set layout of the frame before adding components to it)

```
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // move this line
    this.add(mainPanel); 

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        buttonList.add(new Button(""+i));
        buttonPanel.add(buttonList.get(i));
        buttonList.get(i).addActionListener(this);
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Fixed; didn't see he declared the layout after adding a component.

Comment: @Jiman You might like to explain why setting the layout manager after the fact is a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 2):

Recommendations:

- Don't set the JFrame's layout to BorderLayout -- its contentPane *already uses* BorderLayout.
- Don't use a BorderLayout constraint when adding a component to a GridLayout-using container.
- Use JButtons, not Buttons (Swing components, not AWT components)
- Don't set the size of anything. Instead override `getPreferredSize()` returning the desired Dimension.
- Even better, let the components size themselves to their best size.
- You always want to call `pack()` after adding all components to the top-level window (here the JFrame) and before calling `setVisible(true)`.

For example,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UI extends JFrame {
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(800, 800);
   private ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
   private JPanel buttonPanel;

   public UI() {
      super("Elevators");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12, 1));

      add(mainPanel);

      for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
         buttonList.add(new JButton("" + i));
         JButton btn = buttonList.get(i);
         buttonPanel.add(btn);
      }
      mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return PREF_SIZE;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      UI frame = new UI();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

which displays as,

[image: Button Panel Image]

**Edit 2**
Consider using BorderLayout for the overall GUI, the two elevator images could be placed in the BorderLayout.LINE_START and BorderLayout.LINE_END positions. The elevator JPanels that could use null layout to allow the elivator component to change position. The central JPanel could also use BoxLayout oriented in a BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS (vertical).

Comment: This won't answer the question.

Comment: @M.M. getting rid of the `setLayout(BorderLayout)` will. Test it.

Comment: @M.M. Probably not, but it's still great advice that will make the OP's life easier

Comment: Thanks, at least I got buttons to show haha. How would I change this if I want them to be just in the center of the screen? For example I want to have 3 panels (the button panel being the center one) w/ two canvases on the panels to the right and left of the button panel.

Comment: @Big: Please show a picture of your desired layout in your original question. As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words.